# How can an angular element subscribe the event emitted by the host?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have an angular element `custom-element`, which emits an event `action`, to which I can subscribe using -

```
const el = document.querySelector('custom-element');    
el.addEventListener('action', (event) => {
  console.log(`"action" emitted: ${event.detail}`);
})
```

So I am able to listen to events emitted by the `custom-element`. But I also want to make `custom-element` listen to events emitted by the host. How can I do that?

One way I can think of is passing an observable as an input and let `custom-element` subscribe to it. Is it a good solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## USE @HostListener:

```
@HostListener({ 
  eventName?: string
  args?: string[]
})
```

found [here](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)